# Monotouch add border to gradient

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, drawing, gradient

I am trying to add borders to a gradient button:

```
var c = bdPencil.ColorMain;
Context.SetLineWidth(bdPencil.Width);
Context.SetStrokeColor(c.R, c.G, c.B, c.A);
Context.Clip();
CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradient gradient = new CGGradient(colorSpace, colors, 
new float[]{ 0, 1 });
Context.DrawLinearGradient(gradient, new PointF((float)r.CenterX, (float)r.Top), new PointF((float)r.CenterX, (float)r.Bottom), 
CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation);
Context.RestoreState();
```

and it is not working.
Everything is working if I do the same thing with a solid color:

```
  var c = bdPencil.ColorMain;
  Context.SetLineWidth(bdPencil.Width);
  Context.SetStrokeColor(c.R, c.G, c.B, c.A);
  var g = bgPencil.ColorMain;
  Context.SetFillColor(g.R, g.G, g.B, g.A);
  Context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
```

When I am trying to stroke the path after the `DrawLinearGradinet` nothing happens.
I suppose I need something like GradientStroke but I can't find it.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that I tried doing everything with the context.
I drew a path, stroked it and then I drew the gradient and it worked.